# trying to log the sent arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, arguments

```
function log(tobelogged){
    if (debugging){
        c.log(arguments);
        c.log(arguments.toString());
        c.log(tobelogged);
    };
};
```

and then

```
log(someObject);
```

and I want to response

```
'someObject'
'whatever is in someObject'
```

I tried toString() above but clearly I'm missing something. How do you get the 'name' of what's sent to the function? The example uses oni apollo stratified sjs in the browser but I don't think it matters here. Anyy ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An argument doesn't have a name. It only has a reference via a parameter, or via an index of the `arguments` object. The parameter name is an indirect reference from the parameter to an index in the `arguments` object.

In *strict mode*, there's even less of a correlation, since you can modify the values of the *parameters* without affecting the value of the *arguments object*, and vice versa.

I think the closest you'll come is using...

```
console.dir( arguments ); // instead of console.log
```

...which should give you an expandable object, so you can see the arguments by index.

[image]

Comment: As you say, doesn't do what I wanted though.

Answer (score 1):

That information is lost and not available in `arguments`.

You could set a break point there (throw in `debugger;`) and examine the call stack.

Comment: You're right, there's no shorthand way to do what I want. Though I'm not how to use the debugger command, reading.. Thanks.